# Is there any way to make an email's subject bold?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending email using C#.NET, for which I am using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class. I want to make a portion of the email's subject bold. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Well first, you have to find a mail client that supports a bold subject. As far as I know, most email clients set the subject in a set way, which is to say not bold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no way to format the subject of an email message with font styles, weights, faces, color, etc. It is plain-text only.

It's not a limitation of .NET, rather it's the way email is.

Answer (score 3):

While you have no control over the subject, you could hint to the email clients that a message is important by setting the priority.  Depending on the client, it might be highlighted in some way.

eg

```
message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
```

Since people abuse this, email clients could very well ignore it.  But see if it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

Well actually there's a *not-so-pratic* way, you'll need to combine characters entities to do so, take a look at this page

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/list.htm

and try some styles here

https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=style+my+subject

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are now Browser Extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formatted-email-subject-l/lbnejjahbkciooojokighdfkmcgkpjfb/related, which may help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way - and icons etc - just check your spam for examples... (here is one from today)

```
From: Diamond Hand Insider <that@your.diamondhandinsider.com>
To: 
Subject:  ’   EXPOSED
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2023 12:34:36 -0600
List-Unsubscribe: etc
```

but not sure its a great idea, I think this will make it more likely to flagged as spam. They are using the unicode symbols I believe

Comment: I've commonly seen the "[Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1D400.html)" code block abused in this way. Sometimes also the "circled" and "squared" letters, for a different look. I wish it were easier to search for these and send them to spam in email clients (looking at you, Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

**Generally: email subject character styles are possible with unicode characters** (for bold, but also italics, serif, sans serif, script...).

So it **will work with any field accepting unicode** (if it accepts emojis = it accepts unicode): email subject, but also social media, WhatsApp, SMS...

A simple way to generate text in the desired unicode format is to use some online tools, like *(I'm not affiliated with any!)*:

- https://capitalizemytitle.com/italic-text-generator/
- https://qwerty.dev/italic-text-generator/
- https://inputoutput.dev/unicode-italic-text-generator/
- https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/
- *... Many others, just Google it!*