# Creating AutoFormatRule filter

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm trying to change the font of an email subject (just the title displayed in the folder) and I don't know how to define the **AutoFormatRule.Filter** property.
Let's say I want to define a rule applying to any message with a certain string inside its body.
Or, if you have a better idea for changing the font of a subject, I'm open to suggestion.
The only example I could find is: (for VB, i'm not even sure how to apply it for c#)

```
 .Filter = """http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f""" & _ " CI_STARTSWITH 'HANDOFF'"
```

[Trying to change the font in this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osBLj.jpg)

Comment: [You cannot change the font of any email's subject line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852812/is-there-any-way-to-make-an-emails-subject-bold)

Comment: @CodingYoshi thank you for you answer, but i'm not trying to change the font of the email itself, just the font of the title displayed in the folder (in the picture). the same way you can do it with conditional formatting option.